# Only few attribute values are displaying , instead of all in the sidebar of site

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.7

I am facing one issue.. (regarding filters)

Iam having filters like color, manufatcurer etc… in the sidebar of my site

### Problem is:

A) Only few attribute values are displaying (instead of all), for eg: “color” attribute has differnt color values like: black, red, blue, yellow etc.. iam just able to see only “black” value in the sidebar of my site , why its not showing me other color attriibute values?

and iam pretty sure that every product has some differnt color value..

Please kindly tell me , what could be issue?

Awaiting for response!

**Edit:** Iam getting attribute values from ‘Import Feed’

Comment: joey have you correctly entered attributes while adding them, sort order etc ?

Comment: @SKV hi, what you mean by correctly entered?

Comment: i mean are they correctly configured while adding ?